# Send Email Address with '@' and '.' (dot) as Parameter - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, url

I have a route in api.php

```
Route::get('pelanggan/email/{email}/', 'PelangganController@cekEmail');
```

In Postman, I tried this API endpoint with this url

`http://localhost:8000/api/admin/pelanggan/email/desiya1@gmail.com`

But it returns me 
`The requested resource /api/admin/pelanggan/email/desiya1@gmail.com was not found on this server.`.

Anyone can help me please, how can I send the `desiya1@gmail.com` with `.com` in this case?

Comment: Try URL encoding the email address.

Comment: seems your server isn't configured properly, what webserver are you using?

Comment: @DaniFadli Try https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @lagbox MySQL, common MySQL

Comment: @user3783243 I have tried `urlencode()` to my request URL. And it replaces the dot with `%2E`. But it returns the same response

Comment: what webserver, not what database

Answer (score 0):

i don't find any error it work for me.in your controller.here admin is your prefix?? try this in your controller

```
public function cekEmail()
{
$email=request('email');
dd($email)
}
```

Comment: Yes I use `admin` prefix

Comment: Your answer didn't help me so much, but thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative. Before the request, I use PHP `str_replace` to replace the dot in the email address with another symbol like `*`. Then, I send it as an API endpoint's parameter. So, now I have `desiya1@gmail*com` in my request.
And in the server, I use `str_replace` again to replace the `*` with the dot. So I have `desiya1@gmail.com` again.

Thanks for your approaches guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function cekEmail($email)
{
  dd($email)
}
```

I got the email in the dd.
[check the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsOh3.png)

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it, but it still returns `The requested resource /api/admin/pelanggan/email/desiya1@gmail.com was not found on this server` when I put a dot in the address. I've found the alternative, at least for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble, then I run

```
php artisan serve
```

and call `http://localhost:8000/api/show/file/hack.pdf`
it works very well.
It took me couple hours to realize that using `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` gave me that not found error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33157637)